# How to join pandas dataframes based on wildcards?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, wildcard

I have two dataframes df & df2 and I would like to merge them with * as wildcard

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[".",".",1],["AB.","B.",3],["B.",".",2]]
data2 = [["A","B","1"],["ABC","BC",4],["B","A",2]]
columns = ["Type1","Type2","Value"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=columns)
print(df)
print(df2)
  Type1 Type2  Value
0     *     *      1
1   AB*    B*      3
2    B*     *      2
  Type1 Type2 Value
0     A     B     1
1   ABC    BC     4
2     B     A     2
```

Typically here the second line of df2 should match with line 1 and line 2.
Whereas line 0 in df2 should only match the first line of df1.
Somehow I would like to get something like

```
df2.merge(df,how='left',on=["Type1","Type2"])
```

But the result here is not matching anything.

This is the result that I would like to get.

```
data3 = [["A","B","1","1"],["ABC","BC",4,1],["ABC","BC",4,3],["B","A",2,1],["B","A",2,2]]
columns3 = ["Type1","Type2","Value_x","Value_y"]
results = pd.DataFrame(data3,columns=columns3)
print(results)
  Type1 Type2 Value_x Value_y
0     A     B       1       1
1   ABC    BC       4       1
2   ABC    BC       4       3
3     B     A       2       1
4     B     A       2       2
```

Please note that the df2 table actually has more than 1 million lines so I can't afford to do a loop for efficiency reasons.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Ok i just did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use the code below. This transfer the dataframe into a SQLite database, then performs the join and finally brings it back to another dataframe. This is not optimal but it works.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
df.to_sql('df', conn, index=False)
df2.to_sql('df2', conn, index=False)
query = """
SELECT [df2].[Type1],
       [df2].[Type2],
       [df2].[value],
       [df].[value]
FROM   ([df]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [df2]
                     ON [df].[type1] LIKE [df2].[type1]
                     AND [df].[type2]   LIKE [df2].[type2])
"""
df3 = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
conn.close()
```